# How do I figure out the width, of a Bootstrap Column, on a Mobile device?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Photoshop, to create a series of Wireframes, for a future eCommerce website.

I understand that Bootstrap operates on a '12 column' basis.  The width, of each column, dependent on the device it is being viewed on.

Whilst going through Bootstrap's website, I came across this image:

[image]

My current Wireframe is for a screen width of 360px.  To figure out the column width, I divided the 360px by 12, as to reach 30px.  By factoring the Gutter Width of 30px, as displayed in the above image, I am left with 0px for the content to be placed within the Column.

Where could I be going wrong with this?  I would like to figure out the width of each Column, on  a mobile device.

Comment: Do you really want 12 columns at 360px?..if so, what for? The width classes take care of this for you, don't they?

Comment: on mobile you would most likely only use col-12 or col-6. Why do you really need a col-1?

Comment: Once you use a col-4 on mobil. You will have 30px of gutter and 120px of content.

Comment: From a Wireframing perspective, I was under the impression you create the 12 columns, within the design, and then assign how many columns you would like each feature to occupy when implementing the design into the Front End.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Wouldn't that be 90px for content?  120px - 15px of Gutter either side of the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Wireframing perspective, even though you *can* operate with 12 columns on the smallest screens, you should NOT. Instead, you should only use **one** column i.e. full width or **two** columns at the most on the smallest screens.

Also, the smallest screen is 320px wide, not 360px.

320px - 30px (15px for left and right margin) = **290px** is what's left for content on the smallest devices.

290 / 12 = 24.2px per column including gutters! That's why you should not utilize all 12 columns on the smallest screens (unless you have something very tiny such as icons).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I was using my own mobile device, at 360px.  I have seen many websites, where they would have, for example, a logo, then 3 icons on the same row.  Wouldn't this be 4 columns?  I was just under the impressions, you implement the 12 columns and then assign how many columns you would like to occupy, within the front end coding.  For example, if an icon was 50px, you would 'say' the icon occupied 2 columns, within the 12 columns.

Comment: That depends very much on the layout. You could put all those things into a single full-width column and still get them spaced out as needed. Bootstrap 4 has very neat spacing utilities that allow doing the spacing automatically. So, it doesn't work quite the way you think it does. Instead, we rely on the flexbox utilities etc. to do the spacing automatically while placing everything into a single column.

Comment: If you are unsure how to create a particular layout in Bootstrap 4, feel free to post a separate question for that. But basically, it's by using a combination of flexbox utilities, margin and padding utilities.

Comment: For example, `mx-auto` will center things in the navbar. Or adding the `ml-auto` class the right-most of 3 groups/items will center space out all 3 groups very neatly.

Comment: Ok, great.  Thank you for your time and insight.

Comment: Sorry, just to double check.  Say I did use the 12 columns, have I understood it right, in that there would be an overlap of columns, since each Columns' gutter of 30px exceeds its allocated 24.2px on a mobile device?

Comment: No, there won't be any overlaps. If I use a class like `col-12` that class says: "give this column 12 units" and since a row can have a maximum of 12 units (as a sum of the columns inside) that one column will be full-width. And if the whole thing is wrapped in a `.container`, then there will be 15px margin on left and right.

Comment: So, we only use full width (typically) for small screens. However, if you did put 12 columns with one unit each into a row, then, on the smallest screens, those columns that don't fit, will be automatically pushed down but they won't overlap. So, if you have, say, 12 of these divs: `<div class="col">i</div>`, even with the narrowest letter i inside they won't fit into one row on a 320px screen. One of them will be pushed down and the more content you add into the columns, the more of them will be pushed down.

Comment: Correction: Only 9 of those divs from my previous comment fit on one line on a 320px wide screen. The rest will be pushed down.

Comment: Great.  Understand the columns now.  Thanks, once again! :-)